# mutt: problem when running from pure-uploadscript of pure-ftpd

Tags: ftp, mutt

- Ubuntu Jaunty Server (9.04)
- pure-ftpd 1.0.21-11.4ubuntu1
- mutt 1.5.18-6ubuntu1

I need to receive e-mail notifications when my FTP users upload files.

I use pure-uploadscript to do this. The code below is set to be run from my own (non-super) user:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "File $1 (size $UPLOAD_SIZE) uploaded by $UPLOAD_VUSER \
on $(date)" \
| /usr/bin/mutt -s "[FTP] File uploaded: $1" \
  user@example.com 2>&1 >> path/logfile \
&& echo "OK $1 $(id)" >> path/logfile \
|| echo "ERR $1 $(id)" >> path/logfile
```

My script gets called, $(id) displays correct data, but mutt says (as I can see from the log) "Could not send the message.".

When I run the same command from the commandline of my own user, message is sent.

What can I do to debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutt is probably looking at the wrong place for the sendmail command.

`:set sendmail` from within mutt gives you the location where mutt is looking for it. It can also be used for setting the right location e.g. `:set sendmail="/usr/sbin/sendmail"`

As a side note, mutt is a great program, but `nail` or `mailx` are usually the tools of choice for use in a script.

Comment: I've switched to mailx, and all worked out-of-the-box. Thank you!